# Set Lua function environment while retaining upvalues, with pcall

Tags: lua

I want to invoke a function in Lua (5.3), modifying the environment to inject additional functions to be available, and do so (a) without modifying the code for the function itself, and (b) using `pcall` to invoke the function, able to catch errors.

For example:

**foo.lua** (not allowed to modify the content of `t:foo()`)

```lua
local t = require('lib')()

local b = 17
function t:foo()
    local a = 42
    print(a + b + c())
end

t()
```

**lib.lua** (can change anything here to make this work)

```lua
local lib = {}
function lib.c()
    return 41
end

local function go(t)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if 'function'==type(v) then print(pcall(v)) end
    end
end

return function()
    return setmetatable({}, {__call=go})
end
```

I would like to modify the above to get `lib` injected into the `_ENV` chain for the function when invoked, so that I get the result of running foo.lua:

```
100
true
```

instead of its current output of:

```
false   foo.lua:6: attempt to call a nil value (global 'c')
```

I'm pretty sure I made this (or something equivalent) work in 5.1, but now that `setfenv()` is gone I cannot figure out how I modify the environment for an existing function that I'm going to run, that I can't modify the source of. `_ENV` seems to have very limited functionality, but I'm assuming that I'm missing the knowledge of how it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Does it work for you?

**foo.lua**

```
local L = require('lib')
local print=print
_ENV=L

local b = 17
function t:foo()
    local a = 42
    print(a + b + c())
end

t()
```

**lib.lua**

```
local lib = {}
function lib.c()
    return 41
end

local function go(t)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if 'function'==type(v) then print(pcall(v)) end
    end
end

lib.t= setmetatable({}, {__call=go})

return lib
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution. I don't *like* the line `_ENV=L` because it makes the change affect every function in that file instead of just children of `t`...but that's maybe OK. It also means one extra line of magic that users of `lib` need to know to type, instead of having `lib` perform the magic itself. But it is a lot simpler than the `setfenv()` solution I posted.

Comment: Wow, it took me a minute to realize that `t` was 'global' to `foo.lua` because of the environment swap where it had been set. That's a fascinating concept. I'll need to stew on the possibilities this might yield for an elegant library. (FWIW, this yet-another-unit test library, me updating [Lunity](https://github.com/Phrogz/Lunity) to play nicely with 5.3.)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, by way of [this article](http://leafo.net/guides/setfenv-in-lua52-and-above.html) which provides pure-Lua replacements for `getfenv` and `setfenv` (relying on the `debug` library).

Full code follows, but the solution is roughly:

```
setmetable(lib, {__index=getfenv(function_to_call)})
setfenv(function_to_call, lib)
pcall(function_to_call)
```

---

```lua
require 'debug'

local function setfenv(fn, env)
  local i = 1
  while true do
    local name = debug.getupvalue(fn, i)
    if name == "_ENV" then
      debug.upvaluejoin(fn, i, (function()
        return env
      end), 1)
      break
    elseif not name then
      break
    end

    i = i + 1
  end

  return fn
end

local function getfenv(fn)
  local i = 1
  while true do
    local name, val = debug.getupvalue(fn, i)
    if name == "_ENV" then
      return val
    elseif not name then
      break
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
end

local lib = {}
function lib:c()
    return 41
end
setmetatable(lib,{})

local function go(t)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if 'function'==type(v) then
            getmetatable(lib).__index=getfenv(v)
            setfenv(v,lib)
            print(pcall(v))
        end
    end
end

return function()
    return setmetatable({}, {__call=go})
end
```